# AWS EC2 WordPress PHP-FPM trap invalid opcode

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

Install WordPress on AWS EC2 , but when request the /wp-admin/themes.php /wp-admin/plugins.php

/var/log/message:
Apr 18 04:35:04 ip-10-254-19-18 kernel: [34386163.779360] traps: php-fpm-5.5[2045] trap invalid opcode ip:7f72263fc460 sp:7fff717f2d48 error:0 in libfreebl3.so[7f72263ab000+70000]

MYSQL + PHP5.5 + PHP-FPM 5.5 + Nginx + WordPress 3.8

Comment: Which OS are you using, and how did you install php? I suspect there is an issue with one of the packages you are using, but it will be pretty difficult to track down.

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head against this issue all day too.

I tracked it down to the `rpm package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-9.15.amzn1.x86_64`.  [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) have just now released a newer version, `nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.0-1.19.amzn1.x86_64`, and updating to this has fixed the issue for me.